# How do I prevent the PopupMenu from disappearing when I press space bar within the TextField in it in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, textfield, flutter-web

Here's the snippet of the code in the PopupMenuButton (in Flutter Web):

```
PopupMenuButton(
   offset: Offset(100, 100),
   elevation: 5.0,
   child: ListTile(
   dense: true,
   leading: Icon(
      Icons.filter_vintage,
      size: 16,
     ),
   title: Text('Menu'),

   itemBuilder: (context) => [
       PopupMenuItem(child: Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
           child: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              cursorColor: kLeadingOrangeColor,
              style: kFilterButtonTextStyle,      
              onChanged: (input) => searchNameString = input,
              onEditingComplete: onEditingCompleteCallBack,
              controller: searchController,
         )),
       ]),
```

Then here is the short recording. Notice the PopupMenu disappeared when I press

[image]

So the problem is that every time I pressed space bar, the PopupMenu disappear. What I need is the PopupMenu persisted until I press  or click somewhere else. Anyone knows where might be the problem?

Here is my `flutter doctor`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0-7.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I think the problem may lie in the `onEditingCompleteCallBack`. Is there any logic in that function which might have some affect on the textfield?

Comment: @sixtysticks thanks for commenting. But that call back will only be called when user submits by pressing `enter`. Moreover, that call back was only storing the value to a variable, nothing special. I have found the solution and have posted it below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

The problem is with the `handleTap` method in the `PopupMenuItem` class.

```
 @protected
  void handleTap() {
    Navigator.pop<T>(context, widget.value);
  }
```

So what I did was:

1. Copy the whole class of `PopupMenuItem`
2. Rename it something else. (e.g: `TextFieldPopupMenuItem`)
3. Change the `handleTap` method to:

```
 @protected
  void handleTap() {}
```

4. Use this new class for the text fields.

Then it works!

I think it is because of the abstraction of what we can put inside `PopupMenuItem`, it is hard to determine which input can be taken to dismiss it. However, since I'm using hard keyboard, I think it is not supposed to detect it as a 'tap', but maybe it is up to the Flutter team.

Anyway, this work around works.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPopupMenuItem<T> extends PopupMenuItem<T> {
  const CustomPopupMenuItem({
    Key? key,
    dynamic value,
    void Function()? onTap,
    bool enabled = true,
    double height = kMinInteractiveDimension,
    EdgeInsets? padding,
    TextStyle? textStyle,
    MaterialStateProperty<TextStyle?>? labelTextStyle,
    MouseCursor? mouseCursor,
    required Widget? child,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          value: value,
          onTap: onTap,
          enabled: enabled,
          height: height,
          padding: padding,
          textStyle: textStyle,
          labelTextStyle: labelTextStyle,
          mouseCursor: mouseCursor,
          child: child,
        );

  @override
  CustomPopupMenuItemState<T, PopupMenuItem<T>> createState() =>
      CustomPopupMenuItemState<T, PopupMenuItem<T>>();
}

class CustomPopupMenuItemState<T, W extends PopupMenuItem<T>>
    extends PopupMenuItemState<T, W> {
  @override
  void handleTap() {
     widget.onTap?.call();
  }
}
```

it should be work